# How to create bins for sparse data?

Tags: factor-analysis, continuous-data, sparse

There is a column that has 10 rows of  continuous data , 8 of these 10 rows has 0 and rest has 5 and 10.

How can I divide these into 5 bins.(as rest of my columns which are significant has 5 bins).

Comment: Your data divide themselves in 11 bins, 3 of them populated. Insisting on 5 bins is neither necessary nor helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dataset is so small, why not opt for a [dot plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(statistics)) instead? It removes the need to come up with intervals for single values.